# Get redirected process output into string in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, process, console

I have a WinForms C# application, which uses CefShar to show a local webpage of a jupyter notebook. I start the jupyter notebook with following code:

```
   private string startJupyterNotebook()
    {
        Process consoleProcess = new Process();
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C jupyter notebook --no-browser";

        consoleProcess.Start();

        var reader = consoleProcess.StandardOutput;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var nextline = reader.ReadLine();
            //search for url in output
        }

        consoleProcess.WaitForExit();

        var output = "LinkFoundInTheOutputStringOfProcess";

        return output;}
```

In the Visual Studio Debugger Console I can see the wanted output(url with token), but in the application I do not receive the string of the console. What am I missing?

This is outut of the console in Visual Studio I want to use later:

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/kuehn_c/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-18200-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8863/?token=9825f97d8828e44d1abe977aa087f440a162600c57fd5337
 or http://127.0.0.1:8863/?token=9825f97d8828e44d1abe977aa087f440a162600c57fd5337
```

The whole process of starting jupyter should be hidden from the user and must be shutdown, when the application closes.

Comment: Your question is not _about_ Jupyter, and so the [tag:jupyter] tag is inappropriate. I've removed it. As for the question itself, without a good [mcve] it will be difficult if not impossible to answer the question. However, you should double-check whether the output you seek is actually being written to standard output rather than standard error. As a general rule, you should always redirect both, if you intend to capture any output at all from a process you started. Make sure if you redirect both, you read at least one of the streams asynchronously, to avoid deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It worked out, the output was all ErrorData. I will post the complete solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is because C# application is passing Arguments as Unicode and application where you are sending Unicode arguments is not handling the Unicode arguments.

Try this :

```
consoleProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("/C jupyter notebook --no-browser"));
```

If this would not work, try to create batch file. While calling it through a batch file arguments will be not passed as Unicode.

If you try batch file here is some code which might be helpful.

```
    Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\test.bat"
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory =  @"C:\Users\"
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

And then in test.bat just write this :

```
start "" "c:\application.exe" /C jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

Comment: I tried your Encoding solution, but it did not work out. I will try your bat try next

Answer (score 0):

```
    private readonly ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    private Process consoleProcess = new Process();

    private string consoleText;

    void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.Contains("http"))
        {
            string data = e.Data;
            int pos = data.IndexOf("http:");
            consoleText = data.Remove(0,pos);
        }
    }

    void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data + "\n");
    }

    private string startJupyterNotebook()
    {
        consoleProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        consoleProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
        consoleProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);


        consoleProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C jupyter notebook --no-browser";
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        consoleProcess.Start();

        consoleProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

        var link = consoleText; //"http://localhost:8888/tree/";

        return link;
    }

    public BrowserForm()
    {
        var jupyterLink = startJupyterNotebook();

        InitializeComponent();

        Text = "CefSharp";
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        if (consoleLog == null)
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost:8888/tree/");
        }
        else
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(jupyterLink);
        }

        toolStripContainer.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);

        browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;
        browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
        browser.ConsoleMessage += OnBrowserConsoleMessage;
        browser.StatusMessage += OnBrowserStatusMessage;
        browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChanged;
        browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;

        var version = string.Format("Chromium: {0}, CEF: {1}, CefSharp: {2}",
           Cef.ChromiumVersion, Cef.CefVersion, Cef.CefSharpVersion);

        DisplayOutput(string.Format("{0}, {1}", version, environment));
    }
```